# How the information is related to time in physics?

Tags: time, information

The interpretation of information in physics is confined to assuming instant interactions and stationary states. Today we started to learn that when having higher resolution measurements, even most quantum states are temporal processes rather than jumps between states. Also, the known interactions have propagation speed.
Also, the bit in electronic communication has rising and falling edged, bit width and propagation speed. Are there any attempts to handle state transitions and propagation delay in information theory?

Answer (score 0):

Time and propagation speed feature in Shannon’s classical [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).

Comment: No, they are not. Instant interaction assumed (not not wave propagation speed with its frequency), and is is is valid for the digital communication only. The information arrives instantly to Gamma Centauri.